# How would a nested subquery look if its purpose is to count values between tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

The tables [...] have the following relevant attributes:

RENTAL **(member_id, title_id)**

MEMBER **(member_id, last_name, first_name)**

The task is to count the number of times each member has borrowed a certain book. For example, a member with **member_id** 102 could have 2 entries in the rental table for the book with **title_id** 99. For each member, show the number of times he has borrowed each book.

Now, this is how my (terrible) idea went:

```
SELECT m.member_id, r.title_id, m.last_name, m.first_name, count(*)
FROM (SELECT rr.title_id, m.member_id
      FROM rental rr
      WHERE rr.title_id > = r.title_id and m.member_id = rr.title_id)   
FROM member m,
     rental r  
WHERE m.member_id = r.member_id
```

It doesn't work and I would appreciate if someone guided me through what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Only one `FROM` for each `SELECT`!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why do you want a subquery?

Comment: @jarlh It came natural to me to do it that way, since I want a column telling me the number of times each book was borrowed, for each book entry

Comment: I'd simply JOIN the tables and GROUP BY.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for the tips and your time, trying that right now

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this...

```sql
Select
    m.MEMBER_ID,
    m.LAST_NAME,
    m.FIRST_NAME,
    r.TITLE_ID,
    Count(r.TITLE_ID)  "BORROWED"
FROM
    MEMBER m
INNER JOIN 
    RENTAL r ON(r.MEMBER_ID = m.MEMBER_ID) 
GROUP BY
    m.MEMBER_ID,
    m.LAST_NAME,
    m.FIRST_NAME,
    r.TITLE_ID
```

If you join the tables you can still use aggregate functions, like Count(), and group the data by columns that are not aggregated. This should do the job.
Regards...

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT m.member_id, 
       m.last_name,
       m.first_name,
       r.num_rentals
FROM   member m
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT title_id,
                COUNT(*) AS num_rentals
         FROM   rental r
         WHERE  m.member_id = r.member_id
         GROUP BY
                r.title_id
       ) r
```

or you could use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT m.member_id, 
       m.last_name,
       m.first_name,
       r.title_id,
       COALESCE(r.num_rentals, 0) AS num_rentals
FROM   member m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT member_id,
                title_id,
                COUNT(*) AS num_rentals
         FROM   rental
         GROUP BY
                member_id,
                title_id
       ) r
       ON (m.member_id = r.member_id)
```

or, moving the aggregation to the outer query:

```sql
SELECT m.member_id, 
       MAX(m.last_name) AS last_name,
       MAX(m.first_name) AS first_name,
       r.title_id,
       COUNT(r.title_id) AS num_rentals
FROM   member m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN rental r
       ON (m.member_id = r.member_id)
GROUP BY
       -- group by the primary key
       m.member_id,
       r.title_id
```

If you use an `INNER JOIN` then you will not get any results when a member has not borrowed any books.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VAFpI4A0)